# Problema AUTO_INCREMENT MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tive um problema em que a partir do ID 35218, as contas começaram a ser inseridas a partir do ID 400000, porém não lembro de ter mexido no valor do AUTO_INCREMENT. O que posso fazer para as contas voltarem para menor ID vazio?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que provavelmente aconteceu é alguma inserção de número alto, provavelmente 400000, que subiu automaticamente o incremento. O autoincrement sempre vai ser maior, nem teria sentido querer voltar para número anterior. Qual é o problema em deixar como está? Autoincrement não foi feito para ser sequencial, e sim único.

Comment: Voltar pra seguir a sequência mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Antes de mais nada você deve verificar se existe algum problema na sua inserção, utilizando um bloco de exceção, quando você tenta inserir algo e ocorre algum erro, mesmo assim a sequência muda, é possível modificar a sequencia do `auto_increment` da sua tabela utilizando o código:

```
ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 352019;
```

O problema é que se fizer isso vai chegar um momento que ele irá alcançar o número: 400000, e se o campo for uma chave primária você terá problemas, pois estará violando uma chave única.

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, a questão são as linhas que inseriram nesses números maiores, pra converter elas pro menor número livre.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de converter para o menor número livre, está tabela tem relacionamento com outras tabelas, ou seja, o campo chave é foreign key em outras tabelas? Se sim, aconselho a não mexer nisso...

Comment: Porque pretendo mudar o número máximo de IDs para 100.000, e com esses números altos fica estranho